# In the context of hotels, what's a "purser"?

Tags: hotels, terminology

In the [Winter Package](https://www.shangri-la.com/en/sydney/shangrila/offer-detail/rooms-suites/winter-package-2/) hotel offer, one service provided to Horizon Club members is a "Purser service", without any explanation of what a purser is. Wikipedia's article on [pursers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purser) only talks about pursers in the context of boats and aircraft, as does [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/purser). In the context of hotels, what's a "purser"?

Comment: From a little Google searching, it doesn't look like this is a standard industry term.  Indeed, the top hit for "hotel purser service" is [a job posting for a Purser at that very same hotel](https://www.hosco.com/en/job/shangri-la-hotel-sydney/horizon-club-purser-142185), followed by lots of irrelevant hits.  So maybe it's something that this particular hotel invented.  But the job posting can give you some idea of what a Purser does at this hotel.

Comment: @NateEldredge that sounds like an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From Nate's comment:

It doesn't look like this is a standard industry term. Indeed, the top hit for "hotel purser service" is [a job posting for a Purser at that very same hotel](https://www.hosco.com/en/job/shangri-la-hotel-sydney/horizon-club-purser-142185), followed by lots of irrelevant hits. So maybe it's something that this particular hotel invented. But the job posting can give you some idea of what a Purser does at this hotel:

> - Prepares pre-registration and VIP reservations as well as pre arrival email.
> - Prepares arrival and ensures a smooth check-in and escort to guest room or lift as a minimum.
> - Obtains departure details from guests and updates relevant information in the computer.
> - Prior to guest departure sends an up-to-date copy of the bill
> - Maintains guest history
> - To assist colleagues with efficient and friendly Food and Beverage service. This includes set up and breakdown of the buffet, maintaining a clean and tidy Lounge, clearing & resetting tables
> - Ensures the immaculate physical appearance of the Lounge area

Comment: Sounds like a low-budget version of what some fancy hotels (eg. St Regis) call "butler service".

Comment: Cruise ships have pursers,  Check http://www.vliaison.in/hotel-operations-department.html for example. Chief Purser/Hotel Manager: The Chief Purser oversees the daily operations of all departments onboard a cruise ship except the deck, engine and entertainment departments. He supervises all staff and crew in pursers, housekeeping, and food and beverages departments. Also see https://www.princess.com/careers/shipboard-cruise-jobs/onboard-careers/

Comment: That job description sounds like a general reception/lounge gofer with a grandiose title.